# SSRS dosn't show in ReportViewer using EntityFramwork DataSource

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, reporting-services, webforms, reportviewer

I want to make reporting page using SSRS rdlc in ReportViewer Control

here my ReportViewer code

```
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
        <rsweb:ReportViewer ID="ReportViewer1" runat="server" Height="510px" Width="978px">
        </rsweb:ReportViewer>

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

Then here my control code

```
Imports Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms

Public Class ReporingForm
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        ReportViewer1.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local
        ReportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = Server.MapPath("Reporting.rdlc")
        Dim entities As DepenseEntities = New DepenseEntities
        Dim datasource As ReportDataSource = New ReportDataSource("Dossiers", (From dossier In entities.Dossier.Take(10) Select dossier))
        ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear()
        ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(datasource)
    End Sub

End Class
```

I get no execution error, but my ReportViewer Keep Refreshing in infinite loo

here my result web page

[image]

Note that i'm using MVC Application in my project and WebForm for reportViewer

Comment: I can't see the image - due to network restrictions, but, have you tried see in SQL Profiler or equivalent program if indeed, the queries made for fill the report are being made multiple times? also, have you test your query logic and see whether are errors there? - I can't remember, but, try post the code (*in your Page_Load method*) inside a `if` condition: `if (!IsPostBack) { /* add your logic here. */  }`.

Comment: Thanks ! it worked fine when i added condition if (!IsPostBack) { /* add your logic here. */ }

Comment: Well done, Sylver. You can post and accept your own answer. Have a nice day :)